# How To Programmatically Query Google For Search Volume

Tags: javascript, google-search

is there some way I can query Google for the search volume of a specific term? IE I type in "Roofer Chicago" and the result is "880 Searches Per Month"? I have been trying to do research on this but all of the previously vague answers are now certainly outdated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tool like [KWFinder](https://app.kwfinder.com/dashboard?source_id=0&keyword=roofer%20chicago&location_id=0&language_id=0) to determine average monthly search volume. If you [request API access](https://mangools.com/api) then you could programmatically call the api from your Google App Engine application.

[image]

You can also use [Google's Keyword Planner](https://adwords.google.com/home/tools/keyword-planner/) to determine the monthly search volume of a keyword (and closely related keywords). The specific details of this can be found [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3022575?hl=en), but here is what they provide:

> What your search volume statistics mean
>
> Average monthly searches
> ("Avg. monthly searches"): The average number of times people have
> searched for a keyword and its close variants based on the targeting
> settings and date range you've selected. By default, we average the
> number of searches for the term over a 12-month period.

An API for the Keyword Planner can be found [here](https://docs.dataforseo.com/#keywords-data-api).

Comment: is there any free option?